# Rewrite rule to remove trailing %20 whitespace in URLs / Umbraco 404 page doesn't show for these urls

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, http-status-code-404, umbraco, http-status-code-400

Using an Umbraco custom 404 page works for bad/nonexistent paths EXCEPT those ending in %# for example %20, %2, any number or just % alone.

I'm trying to make a redirect rewrite rule in web.config, here is what I'm trying:

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingWhitespace" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])(\/*(\s|\%20)+)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your Umbraco version?